# Javascript async and synchronous ajax ops

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

If I have a synchronous ajax call running, and an asynchronous call is made while that is happening (via setTimeout() )  will the second call stop/interupt/have any impact on the first call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is single-threaded. As a result `setTimeout` calls can only fire while there is nothing else running. It will fire, once the synchronous ajax call completes and the function that made the ajax request yields control by returning.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, a synchronous call (aka *blocking* call) should block execution until the call is finished. From that I'd think the async call should start *after* the sync call has finished?

From the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest):  *You shouldn't use synchronous XMLHttpRequests because, due to the inherently asynchronous nature of networking, there are various ways memory and events can leak when using synchronous requests*